# Will I have a better or bad SEO impact if I republish my articles on sites which adding canonical tags back to our site?

Tags: seo, google

Website like Medium allow us to republish the our content on their site. They will give footer credit as well as they add canonical tag to our site....

If we republish our articles on that type of site, Will I have a better or bad SEO impact for my site?

Comment: Yeah. We get this question quite often. Short answer? DON'T DO IT! Don't even think about it. Cheers!!

Comment: Please be sure to do a search for questions already asked prior to posting. In addition to the linked duplicate, there's also this:  [Will Google punish me if I import a story from my own blog to Medium.com?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/91263/will-google-punish-me-if-i-import-a-story-from-my-own-blog-to-medium-com/91293#91293)

Comment: @closetnoc Thanks for the answer... But according to https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/93601/is-there-seo-conflict-if-making-identical-posts-on-medium-and-on-a-standalone-we seems like it iis ok

Comment: You can likely find other answers that state the opposite. Content marketing by posting to other sites is largely dead. This was nailed down as fact by Panda when many of these sites were penalized. In short, you are giving your work to others in the hopes that it might benefit you. This never really worked. I knew a guy who did this for a year posting article after article with no results. You are far better off marketing your own work via social media.